# How do I work around this bug in Visual Studio 2012 Update 5? Project Properties, Signing

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Here's the form in VS 2012 Update 5 for signing code. You get to it by right clicking a project, going to Properties and selecting the Signing tab. The form is only half displayed.

[image]

Suspecting this might be related to the fact I'm running this on a high DPI screen, I changed the resolution down. No difference. Also tried running VS in Windows 8 compatibility mode. No difference.

I could maybe edit the .csproj file directly but the schema link is broken. Thanks, Microsoft.

Anyone know a workaround? Have logged a bug in Connect.

Comment: Sure, this is a dpiAwareness bug.  It has been fixed of course, the odds they'll fix it for you are rather low.  Use the [workarounds proposed in the superuser.com question](http://superuser.com/questions/509766/cannot-disable-dpi-scaling-for-visual-studio-2012).

Comment: Neither of the two workarounds proposed in that post make any difference, sorry.